# Autocomplete TextBox in c# from values in a Collection

Tags: c#, collections, autocomplete, textbox

Is it possible to have autocomplete in a textbox enabled for values in a collection?

Say the collection is "people" - a group of class "person"

I would like the autocomplete to retrieve the list of values from "person.Surname" etc

Thanks

Comment: What kind of textbox? Winforms, ASP.Net, WPF..?

Answer (score 1):

For a [winforms](/questions/tagged/winforms) `TextBox` there is no such solution. You'll have to build your own `AutoCompleteStringCollection` like this:

```
textBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
textBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Append; // or whatever you need
textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange(people.Select(p => p.Surname).ToArray());
```

If you were talking about [wpf](/questions/tagged/wpf) or [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net), I have not enough experience with textboxes of these frameworks.